# Best practices for CRUD operations on database and UI

Tags: javascript, html, sql, spring-boot

The question I have in mind is a design choice, best practice question. A user has a user interface which contains an HTML table showcasing all the data in a MYSQL table. After viewing the information through this HTML table he is given several input fields allowing him to perform CRUD operations on this table. Should I change the content of the HTML table emulating what has been deleted using Javascript or should I return all the new content from the database and dynamically create a new table. In the second case the tradeoff is more queries to the database, but purer data. However in the first situation there is a risk that the code I will write to update this HTML table is not perfect and causes issues, however reducing query time to the database.

**Consider the folowing example for a delete operation**

```
DELETE FROM OBJECTS WHERE ID=1;
DELETE FROM SUBJECTS_OBJECTS_RELATIONSHIP WHERE ID=1;
```

and several complex queries

**vs in jquery**

`$("#object_id_1").parent("tr").remove()`

As you can see I can simply delete the row where object_id is 1 using jquery without making queries to the databsae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either way...

If you go the 'update' method, then your server after the deletion should return a javascript call that would perform the operation in jQuery:

> $("#object_id_1").parent("tr").remove()

If you go the full update way then first clear the table and then upload all the data, less efficient but also less error-prone. Personally, I would go with the 'update' method.

Comment: I agree, sending a DELETE request to the server, and on ajax return I can delete the entry from the table

Comment: Ok, great, can you please approve my solution?

Comment: I will after finding that no more feedback is being provided

Answer (score 2):

*Sorry, cant comment yet.*

I dont think there is a direct answer, but making some assumptions:

if you will not load same data again (you probably load data to table with something like `for item in data`), probably its ok to just remove on client side. But if you will rerender same data over and over again with removing what was removed on client side, so queries will be heavier anyway as it would in other case. Alsow you would perform this `.remove()` again and again

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad, and there can be many approaches to your predicament. First I would suggest learning an MVC Framework such as Laravel Or CodeIgniter. Both have their benefits and drawbacks. For example Laravel has a steeper learning curve, but can be a great framework. It has an awesome community behind it as well. CI (codeigniter) On the other hand can be picked up fairly easily. Both provide Database Manipulation "Libraries".

Both follow MVC design patterns. And are "Backend" Frameworks. Basically these are frameworks that work with your serverside code. (PHP)

The trend these days is to pair up Backend with Frontend frameworks. So a good framework that comes to mind would be VueJS.

Laravel and VueJS work incredibly well together. You can make a restful backend and use VueJS to send requests via a framework like Axios or even jQuery.

This is a lot of information to take in, so be sure to get ready for long nights of reading up.

Comment: The response I was expecting was an answer stating when deleting information on the UI has its advantages over re rendering data from SQL. I appreciate your recommendation of suggesting different libraries, but I feel in this case a library is just a work around for a problem I have

Comment: Chart data, graph data and the like would be viable data sources that you could simply "delete" from the UI. Keep in mind that database is used to store persistent/permanent data. So deleting information on the UI like preferences, array values and the like will mostly be the only time you would ever consider not removing permanent data. However, for data such as transaction records, user information, and the like, I believe these are the times you would certainly want to use MySQL